# not able to get tomcat server running - startup.bat does nothing

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, soap

when i click on startup.bat , nothng happens.

Here is what I tried -  I made sure that i installed the correct version of tomcat, for windows xp 32 bit. yet nothing happens.

I also created the JAVA_HOME and gave it the correct location of my sdk

here is the error i am getting
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program

Comment: Suggestion: Open cmd.exe and from there run `startup.bat` and post what message you're getting.

Comment: Also, check your logs.

Comment: thanks for the tip, here my error:

Comment: Can you post the value of your JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program

Comment: Not that, post what value you have given for JAVA_HOME? like C:\Program Files\Java ..

Comment: we clicked out of the control panels - systems - advanced -enviromental variables area, and it seemed to not have saved
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07  So i recreated it. now it works

Answer (score 1):

For Tomcat8 a minimum JRE7 is required, please add JRE_HOME in envrionment/system variable

Answer (score 0):

put your `tomcat/bin`  path in your class path and try to start server.